# How to know how many connections are currently open by asp.net MVC3 app using Entity Framework 4.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am having an MVC3 + Entity Framework 4.1 app, currently iam testing it locally on my pc.

I want to know whether i have closed all my connections properly by disposing entities context or not. Also is  there any available method thru which i can see how many connections  are currently open. I am afraid i am not closing all my open connections properly.

Or is there  any other way to check whether through my web app i am closing all my db connections properly or not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With ADO.NET normally you do not open/close physical database connections manually. There is a connection pool handled by the framework. So when you do `new SqlConnection` you are not opening a new physical connection to the database, you are simply drawing one from the pool. And when you call `connection.Close` you are not closing the connection, you are simply returning it to the connection pool so that it can be reused.

So what is important for you is to ensure that your code *holds* connections for as short time as possible and return them to the pool as fast as possible. You may take a look at the [following article](http://betav.com/blog/billva/2007/05/managing_and_monitoring_net_co.html) which goes into more details about connection pooling.

Comment: okie: then how to make sure i am disposing dataContext currently. Actually i want to know this for for my app where iam using ninject for dependency resolution and i think ninejct is not disposing my dbContext. Please look at this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824465/how-to-dispose-dbcontextor-object-in-asp-net-mvc3-app-when-ninject-is-used-as

Comment: this answers the "what's the best practice on connection handling" but not the question that was asked here. 
in some cases we do want to see how many connections are in use even while properly disposing

Comment: @Darin the article link gives me a "Page not found". Do you know an updated link?